# Android and Unity 3D game development

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am starting to explore the game development using unity 3d for android. I have downloaded the trial version of unity 3.3. I went through few tutorials.

I have one question that is not answered. In the normal apps which we develop using eclipse, we can deploy onto mobile by copying the apk file. What about unity 3d? How do I get the game onto my phone. I don't want to publish on market.

Comment: What do you mean? With the [SDK installed](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html) all I have to do is Build & Run - it will already push it to the device. Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Hello as a unity developper I can answer : unity generate for you an APK when you hit publish button and choice android as a target  , you can also change option ( like Debug, quality ,compression ... )

Answer (score 27):

It is possible to transfer your assets to Eclipse. When it's integrated you can debug via your android phone. Be sure to read the tutorial on Unity's homepage. There is a step by step start-up guide and some more. Following links are worth looking at:

- [Getting started with Unity and Android](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html)
- Official - [Integrating Unity with Eclipse](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html)
- Alternative link - [Integrating Unity with Eclipse](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71607-Integrating-Unity-and-Eclipse)

It would seem that the official "*integration*" link is broken so I updated with a forum post that covers the same topic. However I recommend to try with the official link first.

Comment: @Mazze Second link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can simply copy the apk to your device and install it. Unity builds an apk file (and will optionally sign it using a keystore that you provide or let it generate for you). Once it has built that apk you can deploy it normally. You can even have it include a customized manifest in the apk that it builds if you want to (but it generates a nice one from your settings in the unity project by default).

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods for this, as far i understand,

- Using Build Settings--> Build, It builds the apk file that can be installed on your device using `adb install <apk file path and name>`
- Using Build Settigs--> Build and Run. Which automatically installs the apk built apk file on your device if connected

Answer (score 1):

go to file
-build 
-select android platform(your pc has to have android development kit)
-save your apk

Answer (score 0):

As it is still unanswered I try to close this question

First of all, current version of Unity 5.2 is much more powerfull than version 3.3. mentioned in original question.

> What about unity 3d? How do I get the game onto my phone. I don't want to publish on market.

The same way. Unity allows you to publish build as *.apk on ocal machine and then you can just copy it to your phone and install it.

What is more cool, now you can debug your application running on phone. You have to install Unity Remote to the phone and run. Now you can set breakpoints and debug as normally.

If you change your mind and go to publish on Market - Unity will sign your *.apk

Hope this helps someone, good luck!

Comment: Note that this question was asked in 2011, alot has happened in five years.

Answer (score 0):

The Same way you generate the apk through Eclipse like that in unity you need to build the project. For that android sdk and jdk should be installed in your system and u need to show those path in the unity Preferences then u need a google keystore and need to sign in with that key store in the Publisher settings and then u are able to build the apk which will be store in your local system and you can copy that to your mobile and install the apk file.