# Debugging Untiy3d projects on IOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, debugging, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

How to debug Unity projects on IOS or Android devices (in monodevelop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some workarounds.
One example is the Asset Component `KGFDebug`, found [here](http://www.kolmich.at/kolmich/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=112&catid=86&Itemid=475&lang=en).

You can also try to transfer your assets to Eclipse. For more information on this, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506099/android-and-unity-3d-game-development), in specific [Mazze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6508724/571353).